# Magento two payment gateways, one for each product categories

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

At my Magento store, I need to setup a second payment gateway specifically for products in category X.
So at the checkin process, I need to verify the products in the cart, so I'll face one of three cases:

```
1- Cart has products only from category X ==> Payment Gateway 1
2- Cart has products only from other categories ==> Payment Gateway 2
3- Cart has products from category X and products from other category (mixed) ==> Payment Gateway 2
```

Is it feasible? Any already existing extension? 
Any suggestions how can I code that?

Answer (score 0):

First, Install the new Payment Method, Enable it.
Then you can use an observer at the checkout page to check the category for the product added to the cart, then make a simple if condition to enable or disable that payment method in checkout, i mean, show/hide the payment.